# Send form context through an html file by mail

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to send the context of my form rendering an HTML template, which I send by mail, but it sends me on behalf of the fields. Not the data that is entered in the fields.

I've tried several tags in the html file like: {{form.name_field}}. But it doesn't show the information

my funtion or views.py

```
def solit(request):
"""Gestion de solicitudes"""
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SolitForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        subject = 'Bienvenido {}'.format(request.user)
        from_email = 'xxxxxn@xxxx.com'
        html_content = render_to_string('plantillas/mailsended.html', {'form':form,'user':request.user})
        text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, ['xxxxxxxx@xxxxx.com'])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, 'plantillas/mailsended.html')
        msg.send()
        print (form)
    return redirect ('home')
else:
    form = SolitForm()
return render(request, 'plantillas/testform.html', {'form':form})


my forms.py 

class SolitForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    """Formulario de solicitud"""

    model = peticion

    fields = [

        'disponer',
        'razon2',
        'periodo_init',
        'periodo_fin',
        'horas_r',
        'dias_r',


    ]

    labels = {

        'disponer':'Tipo de Solicitud',
        'razon2':'Razon',
        'periodo_init':'Rango de fecha inicial',
        'periodo_fin':'Fecha final',
        'horas_r':'Dias a adicionar, si es mas de 8 horas',
        'dias_r':'Horas a adiciona, si es menos de 1 dia',

    }


my models 

class peticion(models.Model): #Modelo para (solicitar vacaciones y reportar tiempo)
peticion_choice = (
    ('Reportar', 'Reportar Tiempo'),
    ('Vacaciones', 'Vacaciones')
)

disponer = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=peticion_choice, null=True, blank=False)
usuario = models.ForeignKey(users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
razon2 = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=False)
periodo_init = models.DateField(max_length= 255, null=True, blank= False)
periodo_fin = models.DateField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=False)
created_day = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
horas_r = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
dias_r = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False)
```

and this is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h3>Nombre {{ user.nombre }} Apellido {{ user.apellido }}</h3>
   <div>
     {{ form }}
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can send the context of the user logged into the application in that html file, but the context of the data sent in the fields not at the moment, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

Since your form saves an object (an instance of `peticion`) why don't you pass `{'peticion': form.instance}` to your context and then use that to print the various fields you need, e.g. `{{ peticion.disponer }}`. You should not pass a `Form` for printing the values.

Alternatively you can pass `{'peticion': form.cleaned_data}` which will pass the form's `cleaned_data` dictionary to the context.